# Select distinct on joined table

Tags: servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

I have this query

```cs
var q = Db
    .From<Blog>()
    .LeftJoin<BlogToBlogCategory>()
    .Join<BlogToBlogCategory, BlogCategory>()
    .Where( .. )
    .SelectDistinct();

var results = Db.Select<BlogCategory>(q);
```

It generates this SQL:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT "blog".*, 0 EOT, "blog_category".*, 0 EOT 
FROM "blog" LEFT JOIN "blog_to_blog_category" ON
("blog"."id" = "blog_to_blog_category"."blog_id") INNER JOIN "blog_category" ON
("blog_category"."id" = "blog_to_blog_category"."blog_category_id")
WHERE ...
```

I want to select distinct `blog_category` but the select is adding all the `blog` fields also so I am getting duplicate `blog_category` entries.

How do I just select distint the joined table fields?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [OrmLite](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite) the SqlExpression is what builds the SQL query you want executed:

```
var q = Db
    .From<Blog>()
    .LeftJoin<BlogToBlogCategory>()
    .Join<BlogToBlogCategory, BlogCategory>()
    .Where( .. )
    .SelectDistinct();
```

Whilst the API use to execute the query maps the result back to the specified model, in this case you're saying you want the results of the above query mapped to `BlogCategory` POCOs:

```
var results = Db.Select<BlogCategory>(q);
```

But you need to make sure that the query you create returns results that can map to the POCO you've specified.

If you only want to select distinct `BlogCategory` columns you'll need to do this in your SqlExpression:

```
var q = Db
    .From<Blog>()
    .LeftJoin<BlogToBlogCategory>()
    .Join<BlogToBlogCategory, BlogCategory>()
    .Where( .. )
    .SelectDistinct<BlogCategory>(c => c);
```

Or if you want to select columns across different joined tables you'd use a standard anonymous type expression:

```
var q = Db
    .From<Blog>()
    .LeftJoin<BlogToBlogCategory>()
    .Join<BlogToBlogCategory, BlogCategory>()
    .Where( .. )
    .SelectDistinct<Blog,BlogCategory>((b,c) => new { b.Id, c.Name, ... });
```

Then the custom model you map the results to should have properties that match the returned columns:

```
var results = db.Select<BlogCategoryResult>(q);
```

Alternatively you can access the custom result set with the [Dynamic Result Set](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#dynamic-result-sets) APIs.